# Rapid repeated traversing within a div

Tags: javascript

I have a number of divs, each of which contain an instance of a number of different items, each with their own unique classes and/or ids.

A lot of .js code applies to the elements within each of these parent divs, and my .js is getting bloated by the constant need to do things like:

```
// Stuff like this occurs 15-20 times for similar but different actions
$(this).parent().nextAll('.target').eq(0).find('.toggle').slideToggle();
$(this).next('.alert').html('Success');
```

In the context of the *document*, I see why this code is necessary. However, I feel that if I were only able to redefine the reference point as being the parent div instead of the whole document, I could replace the convoluted code above with the MUCH easier:

```
function keepingCodeWithinParentDiv(){
  $('.toggle').slideToggle();
  $('.alert').html('Success');
}
```

So, is there a way to say in Javascript: `for this part nothing exists outside this div`?

Comment: No. But you could still probably clean up with using a common ancestor and making `find()` calls based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a parent element (let's name it `element`) that you want to confine your jQuery selector operations to, you can just pass it as a context to any jQuery select:

```
$(".toggle", element).slideToggle();
```

See [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery) for more info.

If you show us your actual HTML and describe what you're trying to get, we could give more specific advice.

Comment: This is called context.
$(".toggle", element)
is the same as 
element.find(".toggle")